# How to print the variable from another function in main function?

Tags: java

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    
    static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
        char aa[] = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        char bb[] = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        
        if(a.length() != b.length()) {
            return false;
        }else{
            java.util.Arrays.sort(aa);
            java.util.Arrays.sort(bb);
            return java.util.Arrays.equals(aa,bb);
            
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a = scan.next();
        String b = scan.next();
        scan.close();
        boolean ret = isAnagram(a, b);
        System.out.println(aa);
        System.out.println( (ret) ? "Anagrams" : "Not Anagrams");
    }

}
```

Pls help me how to print the variables in isAnagram function to main(). I tried `System.out.println(aa);` in main() but got error:

```
Solution.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(aa);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable aa
  location: class Solution
1 error
```

Comment: Isn't the software you're using for the code alarming you that the variable "aa" is not defined in main? Anyways, one quick way to do it is you could print it in the method "isAnagram" where it's defined.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access variables from isAnagram function in main() because of their scopes. If you want to print them in console, write print statement inside isAnagram method itself

```
static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    char aa[] = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char bb[] = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aa));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bb));

    if(a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }else{
        java.util.Arrays.sort(aa);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(bb);
        return java.util.Arrays.equals(aa,bb);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prepare the char array `aa` in `main` method if you need to print the anagram there:

```java
static boolean isAnagram(char[] aa, char[] bb) {
    if(aa.length != bb.length) {
        return false;
    }

    java.util.Arrays.sort(aa); // `aa` will be sorted outside isAnagram
    java.util.Arrays.sort(bb); // so will 'bb'
    return java.util.Arrays.equals(aa, bb);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a  = scan.next();
    String b  = scan.next();
    char[] aa = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char[] bb = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    boolean ret = isAnagram(aa, bb);
    System.out.println(new String(aa));
    System.out.println( (ret) ? "Anagrams" : "Not Anagrams");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the character array('aa') as a static instance variable and you will be able to access 'aa' in any method.

Try this way;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution{

  static char aa[];

  static boolean isAnagram(String a, String b) {
    aa = a.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    char bb[] = b.toLowerCase().toCharArray();

    if(a.length() != b.length()) {
        return false;
    }else{
        java.util.Arrays.sort(aa);
        java.util.Arrays.sort(bb);
        return java.util.Arrays.equals(aa,bb);
        
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = scan.next();
    String b = scan.next();
    scan.close();
    boolean ret = isAnagram(a, b);
    System.out.println(aa);
    System.out.println( (ret) ? "Anagrams" : "Not Anagrams");
  }
}
```